# Do I need to close pymongo session?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
conn_pf = pymongo.Connection(ip,27023,slaveOk=True)
```

The above allows me to close the session using `conn_pf.close()`.

But:

```
conn_pfname = pymongo.Connection(ip,27023,slaveOk=True).__getattr__(resource+"_pfname").__getattr__("data")
```

doesn't allow me to close using `conn_pfname.close`. It says collection types does not have close method. Did I really open session in my second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to close PyMongo connections. Leave them open so that PyMongo's connection pooling gives you the most efficient performance:

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo

Also, the old APIs like "Connection" and "slave_ok" were deleted from PyMongo years ago, please upgrade to the latest version for the most correct and efficient driver. Use MongoClient:

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: My concern is ,if I open multiple connections (like 200)and do not close them ,then it may be difficult for another production machine(which is more important than my machine) to open a session on mongo because of so many idle connections that I had opened through my script . Am I right?

Comment: Only create one MongoClient and use it for the duration of your program. If your program isn't multi-threaded, the MongoClient will open 2 connections to MongoDB. See the connection pooling FAQ: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo

Comment: How about Jupyter iPython Notebooks? In that context, we have found that our pymongo clients were holding on too many sockets. That is a particular use-case, because each Notebook runs as a separate process and does not terminate.

Comment: While this may be true, having too many open can cause issues. Especially since you can have multiple connections from a single source.

Comment: @snooze92 - I use .close() and it shuts down both connections in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: @ProsperousHeart Agreed. I was mentioning this because I think it's an important gotya. The answer "no" is only valid for a program that needs to keep pooled connections alive for its entire lifetime. Some applications such as iPython notebooks have a very long lifetime and do not need to keep a pool of connection alive.

Comment: @snooze92 - understood. Only issue is if they keep opening a new connection every time they run their code. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure multiprocessed scripts requires you to create multiple clients, using the same across all of them doesn't work. In this case, should I close the connection at the end of the each process' life?